# Spring BeansException local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID

Tags: spring, spring-framework-beans

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'vabmServiceImpl': 
    Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'vabmRmiService'; 

nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'vabmService' defined in class path resource 
    [com/avamar/mc/api/core/configuration/RemoteApiRepository.class]: 
    Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 

nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
    Failed to instantiate 
    [com.avamar.mc.vabm.rmi.VabmServiceRemoteAPI]: 
    Factory method 'vabmService' threw exception; 

nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error 
    unmarshaling return; 

nested exception is: 
java.io.InvalidClassException: 
    org.springframework.beans.BeansException; 
    local class incompatible: 
    stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -2725566157126749441, 
    local class serialVersionUID = 5951866628951717299
```

I am facing this exception during call a project from another spring's project. I am not able to find the solution for this..